# Run command for codeception in yii2

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, codeception

Can anybody provide the run command for Codeception in Yii2 from root folder? I tried

```
vendor/bin/codecept run 'patt/to/testfile'
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

you have to configure the path, where the configuration file is located:

```
vendor/bin/codeception run -c /path/to/config.yml testsuitename /path/to/testfile
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks. Now, I got the fatal error: class not found when run unit test. Seems to be issue with namespace? or with bootstrap file configuration?

Comment: This works fine now. vendor/bin/codeception run testsuitename  /path/to/testfile worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default your config file `codeception.yml` is located in `tests`. As such you can run the command as

```bash
vendor/bin/codecept run -c tests/ testsuitename path/to/testfile
```